# How to emit/merge another observable inside RXJS retryWhen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have an observable for api request, basically I added `retryWhen` in the event connection failed/error. While doing so I want to dispatch another action (no notify the user the system is retrying..) when the request is throwing an error.

```
//....
export const saveArticle1 = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(AUTO_SAVE_ARTICLE_READY),
    withLatestFrom(state$, (a, b) => b),
    switchMap(({
      article,
    }) => {
      const payload = getArticlePayload(article);
      return ajax.patch(`/api/article/${article.id}`, payload, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }).pipe(
        flatMap(({ response }) => of({
          type: ARTICLE_AUTO_SAVED,
          value: response,
        })),
        retryWhen(errors =>
          errors.pipe(
            // TODO: I try to concat or merge observable here but no luck
            delay(1000),
            take(60),
          ),
        ),
        catchError((ex) => {
          articleSaveFailureAlert();
          return showErrorNotification('Api Error. Unable to save this article.')(ex);
        }),
      );
    }),
  );
```

What is the best way to dispatch another action inside `retryWhen`? or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you'll have to go with `tap(() => this.store.dispatch(...))` because I guess you don't want to trigger resubscription with that action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive loop with the stopping condition that the number of attempts made is greater than the maximum allowed attempts. Then you can concatenate a single observable of your "retry" action with the patch observable. If you edit the snippet to change `maxAttempts` to a number lower than 5 you'll see the "failure" action being emitted.

As an aside - you might want to double-check your use of `switchMap` when triggering an API call that makes a persistent change. [Here's an article](https://ncjamieson.com/avoiding-switchmap-related-bugs/) that explains the issue in detail.

```js
const {of, operators, throwError, timer, concat} = rxjs;
const {switchMap, catchError, flatMap} = operators;
const maxAttempts = 60;
const patch = (article, attempt) => {
  if (attempt < 5) 
  return throwError(new Error('server unavailable'));
  return of(article);
};
const action$ = of('patch.id');
const saveArticle1 =
  action$.pipe(
    switchMap((article) => {
      const loop = (attempt) => {      
        return patch(article, attempt).pipe(
          flatMap((response) => of({
            type: 'saved',
            value: response,
          })),
          catchError(error => {
            if (attempt > maxAttempts) return of({ type: 'failed' });
          
            return timer(1000).pipe(
              switchMap(() => 
                concat(
                  of({ type: 'retrying' }), 
                  loop(attempt + 1)
                )
              )
            );
          })
        );
      };
      return loop(0);      
    }),
  );
  
saveArticle1.subscribe({
  next: x => console.log('next', x),
  error: e => console.error(e),
  complete: () => console.log('complete')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.4/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Although I had to change your example a little bit as `switchMap` expect an observables..

`return timer(1000).pipe(switchMap(() => of({ type: 'retrying' }).pipe(concat(loop(attempt + 1)))));`

Comment: @TomMarulak `pipe` is expecting an operator like [concatMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap), whereas [concat](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/concat) returns an observable. Double check that it's doing what you think it's doing

Comment: Sidenote: It's very hard to read through the pyramid of RxJS operator.